# Remove chapter gap in list of figures in report class

Tags: table-of-contents, graphics, floats

I have a list of figure where figures are grouped by chapter (see image below).

[image: list of figures with gaps]

I have already tried numbers of solutions but none of them worked.
Here's a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{report}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
 \listoffigures
 \chapter{chapter1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Figures/fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Figures/fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}


 \chapter{chapter1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Figures/fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Figures/fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}


 \chapter{chapter1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Figures/fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Figures/fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the definition of `\chapter` in the report class. It calls another command `\@chapter` which calls `\addtocontents{lof {\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%` adding vertical space to the list of figues auxiliary file. You don't want this to happen. One way to "fix" this: is to copy the `\@chapter` command into your document and comment out the offending line.

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\makeatletter
%\show\@chapter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
%                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% 
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
 \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
 \listoffigures
 \chapter{chapter1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}


 \chapter{chapter1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}


 \chapter{chapter1}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{fig1.png}
    \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove these gaps by patching `\@chapter`; it inserts gaps in both the List of Figures (`lot`) and List of Tables (`lot`). Patching is done using a search-and-replace technique provided by [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\patchcmd{\@chapter}% <cmd>
  {\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption 1}
  \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption 1}
  \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Third chapter}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption 1}
  \caption{Caption 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You need at least two compilations on the first change in order for the patch to reflect in the LoF/LoT.